# SAPI event SPEI_WORD_BOUNDARY notification doesn't work

Tags: sapi

I have used this function to speak sentence ascynchronously .

```
m_cpVoice->Speak(m_sInputText,SPF_ASYNC, NULL))
```

I want to get notification of `SPEI_WORD_BOUNDARY` event so i did these.

```
m_cpVoice->SetInterest(SPFEI(SPEI_WORD_BOUNDARY),SPFEI(SPEI_WORD_BOUNDARY));
m_cpVoice->SetNotifyWindowMessage(GetSafeHwnd(),CTTSDlgDlg::MSG_SAPI_EVENT,0,0);
```

`CTTSDlgDlg::MSG_SAPI_EVENT` maps to my event handler.

Am i missing something and whats the problem that i am not getting notification?

Comment: What happens if you broaden your event mask?  (E.g., including SPEI_START_INPUT_STREAM & SPEI_END_INPUT_STREAM)?

What voices are you using?

What is the value of CTTSDlgDlg::MSG_SAPI_EVENT?

Comment: MSG_SAPI_EVENT is the window registered message.

Comment: if i use WM_USER as a notification message instead of MSG_SAPI_EVENT then it works fine .
Why is it so ?

Comment: Where are you registering MSG_SAPI_EVENT?  

Also, how are you binding MSG_SAPI_EVENT to your code?  (For example, MFC requires ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE instead of ON_MESSAGE to work properly.)

Comment: Thanks , Ya it worked after using ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFC requires ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE instead of ON_MESSAGE to get your events delivered to your object.

Comment: I think only for registred message MFC requires ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE mapping.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  If you used a message above WM_APP, you could use ON_MESSAGE.  But since you used a registered message, you need to use ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE to handle it.